# Words table hide previous text line

Tags: c#

My project is window form on line one i wrote a text to ms word,then i tried to draw table after that text (on the next line,i mean line 2),the table was visible but hides the previous text. i need the table to be on the next line .how can i solve this error
i also need to write another text after that table

```
start = Type.Missing;
end = Type.Missing;
rng_x = oDataDoc.Range(ref start, ref end);
rng_x.Text = "name ,grade and age etc...  ";
rng_x.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;

start = oDataDoc.Characters.Count;
end = Type.Missing;
rng_x = oDataDoc.Range(ref start, ref end);
Nrow=4; Ncolumn=8;
oDataDoc.Tables.Add(rng_x, Nrow, Ncolumn, ref defaultTableBehavior, ref      AutoFitBehavior);
 Word.Table tbl = oDataDoc.Tables[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer

```
start = Type.Missing;
end = Type.Missing;
rng_x = oDataDoc.Range(ref start, ref end);
rng_x.Text = "hellow";
rng_x.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight;
float wordY = (float)rng_x.get_Information(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdInformation.wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage);
istart = (int)wordY;
iend = (int)wordY;
rng_x.SetRange(istart,iend);
Nrow=4; Ncolumn=8;
oDataDoc.Tables.Add(rng_x, Nrow, Ncolumn, ref defaultTableBehavior, ref autoFitBehavior);
Word.Table tbl = oDataDoc.Tables[1];
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to add some more information on what the exact problem was and what the resolution is to help people in the future that might experience a similar issue